# Excel VBA: Display Image from URL from another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

need some help.

I have been searching around after a code in excel that would let me display and URL as an image. I have found a few good tips and codes but i'm not able to get it how i want.

The Image URL is located in Sheet1 B15 and i what do show the image in a merged cell in Sheet2 B/C-22 to 36. Don't know if it is possible to display it inside the merged cell.

The reason for this is that i need to change the image URL and also Sheet2 is going to be sent as an html email.

Thanks for any help i can get!

Comment: I believe the only way to display an image in a cell is by adding it to a comment.

Comment: You can use record macro. record macro and insert a picture with the URL you have. You can also paste it to range as you wish. You can also use record macro to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, button would work to activate a macro that would make it an image, would like to have it in VBA so it could me automated...

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and the errors you're seeing. See [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vba to insert a picture into a range

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim myTng As Range, myPict As Picture

    Set myRng = Range("B22:C36")
    Set myPict = myRng.Parent.Pictures.Insert(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B15").Value)

    myPict.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    myPict.Top = myRng.Top
    myPict.Width = myRng.Width
    myPict.Height = myRng.Height
    myPict.Left = myRng.Left
    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this will place the picture in the range that i want, and after a few adjustments i got it look good.